How to check if input parameter of timestamp type in oracle stored procedure is null?
We have an oracle stored procedure which accepts multiple timestamp input parameters. This stored procedure is invoked from typescript.
So, when typescript invokes this stored procedure, there is high chance that value for some of the timestamp input parameters could be sent as null.
Can you please help to check if timestamp is null or not in stored procedure.
Please not that we cannot set any default value to timestamp as select statement stored procedure had conditions where it checks for "greater/less than, equals" conditions.
Below stored proc should send message back but it doesn't.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_task_list (
    p_startdate         IN   TIMESTAMP,
    p_enddate           IN   TIMESTAMP,
    .
    .
    .
    p_message           OUT  VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF p_startdate IS NULL THEN
        p_message := 'p_startdate is null ';
    END IF;
    
END get_task_list;

Below is the Typescript code snippet for startdate bind parameter.
    const p_startdate: OracleDB.BindParameter = {
        dir: OracleDB.BIND_IN,
        val: new Date(request.tasklist.startdate as unknown as string),
        type: OracleDB.DB_TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    }

While debugging, we found out that typescript evaluates startdate bind parameter as below:
p_startdate: {
     "dir": 3001,
     "val": null,
     "type": {
         "num": 2012,
         "name": "DB_TYPE_TIMESTAMP",
         "columnTypeName": "TIMESTAMP",
         "_bufferSizeFactor": 11,
         "_oraTypeNum": 180,
         "_csfrm": 0
     }
 }

Versions Used:
"node": "^21.6.1",
"oracledb": "^6.3.0",
"typescript": "^5.3.3"

It looks like you are never passing a null value to the bind parameter in typescript and are always passing a Date object. (And what does the type of p_startdatemax have to do with the parameter p_startdate?)

@MT0, If '' is received as 'startdate' in typescript then new Date(request.tasklist.startdate as unknown as string), evaluates to null even though its type is object. Also, please ignore 'p_startdatemax'. It should be 'p_startdate'. I have updated question.

Your procedure is missing the closing bracket in the signature before the AS keyword. If you fix that then the procedure works in Oracle fiddle (and then any further issues would probably be in the typescript code rather than in the database)

SP has over 200 lines and 32 inputs parameters. So, I took only relevant part of it to post here and missed the closing bracket. SP compiles fine at my end. I am just trying to understand what could be the value of p_startdate parameter in SP? So that I can update the condition within SP?

@Ranjeet, replace your null checking IF statement with an output of the value passed in to see what it's receiving. Or even better, select dump(p_startdate) into  p_message from dual;. that will tell you wnat exactly Oracle is receiving. You would think a null in your client would become a null in Oracle, but I wouldn't assume it until demonstrated.

And make sure you are not overwriting the message later on in the logic.

What is the output of request.tasklist.startdate as unknown as string? Perhaps it cannot be converted into a Date objects.

I don't understand your question: "How to check if input parameter of timestamp type in oracle stored procedure is null?" You do this on your procedure IF p_startdate IS NULL THEN ... - that's the answer!

Parameter p_message was added for debugging purpose and it's used only once in that if condition. Its not used anywhere else in stored procedure.

@PaulW, SQL statement provided by you returns back - Typ=180 Len=7: 255,100,0,0,0,0,0

Type 180 is a TIMESTAMP - you are not passing a NULL value to the procedure.

However, I'm not convinced that you are passing a valid timestamp as that would be 15500-00-00 with negative hours, minutes and seconds which seems invalid on all components. fiddle That appears to suggest that something on the typescript side is building the timestamp in an invalid way.

Have you tried checking if the value is null or an empty string in typescript (assuming from your comment that request.tasklist.startdate has the types string or null)?
const p_startdate: OracleDB.BindParameter = {
    dir: OracleDB.BIND_IN,
    val: (
            (request.tasklist.startdate === null || request.tasklist.startdate === "")
            ? null
            : new Date(request.tasklist.startdate)
         ),
    type: OracleDB.DB_TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
}


More generally:
From your comment that the value of DUMP(p_startdate) is Typ=180 Len=7: 255,100,0,0,0,0,0 then your typescript code is creating an invalid timestamp (with the year 15500, month 0, day 0, hours -1, minutes -1 and seconds -1 - which is invalid in every component).
fiddle
You can reduce the problem space and just directly pass null to the procedure:
const p_startdate: OracleDB.BindParameter = {
    dir: OracleDB.BIND_IN,
    val: null,
    type: OracleDB.DB_TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
}

If that generates the expected message then you know the issue is with the code new Date(request.tasklist.startdate as unknown as string) and if it still generates the same issue then you know the problem is elsewhere.

Yes, this solved the issue. Thanks a lot!!!
